# Wine QLDrivers No ODBC drivers

Tags: drivers, wine, odbc

I run

winecfg

and terminal throw err:

```
0012:err:winediag:SQLDrivers No ODBC drivers could be found. Check the settings for your libodbc provider.
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Try [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in the following way: I installed CDBC on Ubuntu software store, also UnixODBC by terminal, also mysql-shell on Ubuntu software store. I don't know if all of these were really necessary, but I did.
Than, I installed and used playonlinux to install my Database interface app. And, the most important, I installed "mdac28" component into the virtual disc created to run Database interface app. This mdac28 component is necessary to the Database interface app can talk to remote Database server. You can install mdac28 clicking over your Database interface app created inside playonlinux, than, click (in the left side) on "configuration", than clicking on "install component". Scroll up to down until to find mdac28. Than click or double click over it and install it.
After all, click run to use your app.
OK.
Best regards.